# No matching function for lambda with reference argument

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++17

My MWE are the following two files (main.cpp and main.h):

```cpp
#include "main.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        ThreadMap M;

        M.forEach([&](std::pair<int, int>& Pair) {
                // ...
        });
}
```

```cpp
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#include <map>
#include <mutex>
#include <shared_mutex>
#include <thread>

class ThreadMap {
        std::map<int, int> Map;
        std::shared_mutex Mutex;
public:
        using iterator = std::map<int, int>::iterator;

        ThreadMap() = default;

        iterator begin() {
                return Map.begin();
        }

        iterator end() {
                return Map.end();
        }

        template <typename Func>
        void forEach(Func &&func) {
                std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> Lock(Mutex);
                for (auto& Element : Map) {
                        std::forward<Func>(func)(Element);
                }
        }
};

#endif /* MAIN_H */
```

Testing it requires C++17:

```bash
clang -O2 -c main.cpp -o main.o -std=c++17
```

I want to pass a callback function to my class that wraps an STL container with synchronization primitives (the code is shortened dramatically, but the error is the same). Since I want to iterate over every element in the container by reference, I figured that my lambda function also needs to match the reference argument with `std::pair<int, int>&`. However, compiling gives me:

```bash
In file included from main.cpp:1:
./main.h:29:4: error: no matching function for call to object of type '(lambda at main.cpp:6:12)'
                        std::forward<Func>(func)(Element);
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:6:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'ThreadMap::forEach<(lambda at main.cpp:6:12)>' requested here
        M.forEach([&](std::pair<int, int>& Pair) {
          ^
main.cpp:6:12: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::pair<const int, int>' to 'std::pair<int, int> &' for 1st argument
        M.forEach([&](std::pair<int, int>& Pair) {
                  ^
1 error generated.
```

As soon as I remove the `&` in the lambda function for my argument (-> `std::pair<int, int>`), it compiles without any problems. I do not want my loop to generate copies of the elements in the container when iterating, so I believed that the `&` has to stay in the lambda function argument. What did I miss here?

Comment: `std::map<int, int> Map;` is not a map of functions.  Probably you need something like `std::vector<std::function<void (const std::pair<int,int>&)>>` for your function container.

Comment: The value type of `map<int,int>` is **not** `pair<int,int>`

Comment: Sidenote. Returning iterators from such class can be very dangerous. Since map can be accessed through them without locking mutex and this can lead to data race, which is UB. Even `const` iterators won't help if someone modifies map while you reading it through such iterators.

Comment: Read the compiler error carefully. It mentions that there is no conversion from `std::pair<const int, int>` to `std::pair<int, int>&`. Notice the `const`! If you remove the `&` then the compiler can make a copy of the pair, and then it is allowed to remove the `const`. If you just take a reference, it cannot.

Comment: Addressing all of your comments here: It was never supposed to be a map of functions, I worded that poorly. Regarding the value type of the map: This is why staying up until 5 am is not always the best idea... As for the iterators: Yes, this is absolutely correct. I'm still thinking about how to approach this. That's also the reason why I wanted to try to use the `forEach` method instead of exposing a `lock` and `unlock` method so I can iterate over the elements outside of the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I figured that my lambda function also needs to match the reference argument with std::pair<int, int>&

According to [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), the value type of `std::map<Key, T>` is `std::pair<const Key, T>`. Therefore, you need to pass a function that accepts arguments of the type that can be implicitly converted to its value type to `forEach`.

If you want to pass the elements by reference, use `std::pair<const int, int>&`,

```cpp
        M.forEach([&](std::pair<const int, int>& Pair) {
                // ...
        });
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/n654asK63)

As to why remove the reference work, `std::pair<const int, int>` is implicitly converted to `std::pair<int, int>`. It's calling the 5th constructor listed [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair).